# How to stop function reload(window.reload) on jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Source

```
$(function reload(){
  $.ajax({
    .
    .
    .
    window.setTimeout(reload, 3000);
  });
});
```

This function reload ajax page on every 3 sec.

I want to make stop button(#stop).

```
$('#stop').click(function){
   //STOP FUNCTION
});
```

Please let me know how to make it?

Comment: 7 questions, 0 checked. Next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var c =0;

$(function reload(){

  $.ajax({
    .
    .
    .

if(c == 0)    
    window.setTimeout(reload, 3000);

  });

});




$('#stop').click(function){

  c =1;

});
```

Answer (score 3):

To clear a timeout, first you need to assign the value returned by the `setTimeout` function to a variable

```
var timer = setTimeout(...)
```

then use clearTimeout to clear the timer;

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

you may check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout for a detailed explanation.

EDITED: In your case, you may either use setInterval and clearInterval instead, or use a boolean flag to indicate whether to reload or not.

```
var toReload = true;

$(function reload(){
  $.ajax({
    .
    .
    .
    if (toReload) {
      window.setTimeout(reload, 3000);
    }
  });
});

$('#stop').click(function){
   toReload = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the source is something you cannot modify, then you would have to do something hacky, like overriding the `reload()` function:

```
$('#stop').click(function){
   window.reload = function() {};
});
```

If this fails because `reload()` is not under `window`, then you can actually override `window.setTimeout()`, but that's highly not recommended.